# Long-running cuda kernel stops when TDR kicks in

Tags: c++, loops, cuda, sleep

I'm new in CPGPU, and I've got a small. My program needs a really big amount of computing, and so when the timout is reached, and the Windows TDR kicks in, it stops the execution.
Sadly I don't have administrator privileges on the computer my program is running on, so modifying the registry keys is not possible.I managed to decompose the problem into smaller ones by rows of the image being processed, and I tried to call the kernel repeatedly inside a for loop. To ensure that the card do have some time to answer to the OS I've put some sleep-time between the calls, like this:

```
for(int row = 0; row<image.y; row++){
    printf("%d/%d\n", row, image.y);
    cudaMemset(dev_matrixes, 0, image.x*image.y*sizeof(short));
    countEnergyOfRow<<<B,BLOCK_DIM>>>(...);
    Sleep(750);
}
```

At first it seemed to work fine, but at the 21st iteration the driver crushed, and TDR stroke again. After recovery the CPU kept calling the kernel, and the next 490 times it worked fine. I've  ran it multiple times, and every time the 21th iteration was fatal. I also tried to start it from a different (18th) index, but again, the problem occured at the 21st iteration, (at 39th index).
What am I doing wrong, is there something I miss? Should I somehow make the GPU stop counting manually, or just increase the sleep period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Windows TDR, Windows WDDM systems are subject to batching of operations.  So one possibility is that the operations are being batched in such a way that the timeout is exceeded, even if an individual kernel call does not exceed the timeout.

One thing you can try is to simply reduce the execution time of your kernel further.  If the execution time of your kernel is reduced to say, 1/10 second, then even the batching operation should not cause the timeout to be exceeded.

Another thing you could try is to attempt to work around the batching by issuing a `cudaStreamQuery(0);` call after each kernel call.

You might also check to see if the 21st iteration is taking longer for some reason; you could add `cudaEvent` timing to measure the time of each kernel call; I'm sure this would be instructive.

The best solution is to work on a system/GPU that is not subject to WDDM/TDR.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! It really was the batching of operations, that made it run too long. Unfortunately I couldn't shrink the kernel, but adding cudaStreamQuery(0) before the calls did solve the problem.
To be more exact, I added it before the cudaMemset too, because it also very long, and it still stopped sometime. Now it works flawlessly.